# Update attribute in associated model in Rails when parent is updated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I have two models User and Assignment. Whenever User is updated I want to update the url attribute in Assignment.

How do I do this?

```
class User
  has_many :assignments
  ...
end

class Assignment
   belongs_to :user

   before_save :set_url

   def set_sandbox_url
        language = 'www'
        project = 'example'
        base_url = "https://#{language}.#{project}.org/"
        sandbox_url = "#{base_url}/User:#{user.username}/#{article_title}"
   end
```

Comment: Your `before_save` should be in `User` and you use it to update associated assignments. However, User has many assignments so I don't know which one(s) you want to update.

Comment: Thanks for getting back! The url in Assignment uses the Users name so I would need to update every Assignment relating to the User.

Comment: Are you sure you should be storing the URL like that? that should be calculated dynamically rather than stored in a database. This is not WordPress :D

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Tamer Shlash that there is not really a benefit in storing this URL in the database because it can be easily generated each time you need it.

But apart from that, I would like to answer your question. Your callback to regenerate the URL doesn't work for various reasons. First, you want to update the URL when the user changes therefore the user needs to have a callback defined. Second, the naming is not correct. The callback as it is currently written would try to run a `set_url` method but the method is actually called `set_sandbox_url`. And third, `sandbox_url =` will just assign the new URL to a local variable `sandbox_url` but it would not update the instance variable `@sandbox_url`.

I would do something like this:

```
# in app/models/user.rb
after_save :update_assignment_url

private
def update_assignment_url
  assignments.each(&:update_url) if username_previously_changed?
end

# in app/models/assignments.rb
def update_url
  language = 'www'
  project = 'example'
  base_url = "https://#{language}.#{project}.org/"
  sandbox_url = "#{base_url}/User:#{user.username}/#{article_title}"

  update!(sandbox_url: sandbox_url)
end
```

Note: because you build the URL by simply concatenating strings I suggest making sure that these strings (especially values provided by the user like username and article_title) only include characters that are valid in an URL (for example by using [`String#parameterize`](https://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/String%3Aparameterize)).

You might want to read about [Dirty Attributes](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html) too which provided the used `username_previously_changed?` method.